# How to break an image into 9 small ones (sort of puzzle pieces)

Tags: javascript, css, html, sprite

So, I tried creating a little puzzle game, which at the moment looks something like this

[image]

The top is the puzzle where you can put pieces that are chosen from a table with 1 row (scrollable) from the bottom of the page

Problem is those are 9 individual images cut from the original one.

I want to have only one image (the big one) and have them put into the bottom table in a similar manner to what's in the picture above in this post.

For simplicity sake, assume every table cell is `206px width` `124px height`, so the big picture is `618px width` and `372px height` (because that's the size of that random image I found online)

I've set an id to each `td` from the bottom table and tried using css sprite but to no avail.

I'm pretty sure I have to use sprite tho, I just can't seem to make it work. Plus, when I use `background: url()...` it automatically resizes the cells even tho they have a fixed size.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cutting an Image into pieces through Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912917/cutting-an-image-into-pieces-through-javascript)

Comment: NC Wyeth illustrations from Treasure Island. Nice!

Comment: also possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800704/mask-image-into-multiple-portions-without-loading-image-multiple-times/39801079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-position`

*Updated: Thanks to* *@GCyrillus* *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322063/how-to-break-an-image-into-9-small-ones-sort-of-puzzle-pieces/43322326?noredirect=1#comment73713025_43322326) (and [code sample](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gmVKra)), it is now scalable)*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.puzzle {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.puzzle > div {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 33.333%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/1/) no-repeat;
  background-size: 300%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece1] {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece2] {
  background-position: 50% 0;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece3] {
  background-position: 100% 0;
}

.puzzle > div[data-piece4] {
  background-position: 0 50%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece5] {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece6] {
  background-position: 100% 50%;
}

.puzzle > div[data-piece7] {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece8] {
  background-position: 50% 100%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece9] {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="puzzle">
  <div data-piece1></div>
  <div data-piece2></div>
  <div data-piece3></div>
  <div data-piece4></div>
  <div data-piece5></div>
  <div data-piece6></div>
  <div data-piece7></div>
  <div data-piece8></div>
  <div data-piece9></div>
</div>
```

---

Scrambled

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.puzzle {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.puzzle > div {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 33.333%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/1/) no-repeat;
  background-size: 300%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece1] {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece2] {
  background-position: 50% 0;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece3] {
  background-position: 100% 0;
}

.puzzle > div[data-piece4] {
  background-position: 0 50%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece5] {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece6] {
  background-position: 100% 50%;
}

.puzzle > div[data-piece7] {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece8] {
  background-position: 50% 100%;
}
.puzzle > div[data-piece9] {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="puzzle">
  <div data-piece1></div>
  <div data-piece4></div>
  <div data-piece6></div>
  <div data-piece5></div>
  <div data-piece7></div>
  <div data-piece9></div>
  <div data-piece3></div>
  <div data-piece8></div>
  <div data-piece2></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot.

Comment: Just give me a hint real quick. If I use sprite instead of 9 cut images how do I check if the puzzle is solved? before when I had 9 images I would name them 1, 2, 3, etc and I would know where each one should go and just check by `src` attribute.

Is possible instead of having a table for the puzzle itself to have a div and check if it's background url it's the actual image? Not sure if that'd work

Comment: @Hansewl Give each a data-* attribute and check that .... will update my answer in a sec.

Comment: @Hansewl Updated with a better selector and a `data-*` attribute, now you can move them around any way you want

Comment: @Hansewl notice that with **background-size** it can also be resized : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gmVKra (demo uses flex and order to move elements around via animation , not needed for your purpose if you use drag&drop)

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks ... really good suggestion, updated my answer to be fully scalable and linked your codepen

Comment: @Hansewl Updated it with a nice improvment

Answer (score 2):

Based on the size of source image (as whole) you can use javascript to calculate top and left point of each piece. Then allocate fixed size piece divs and set same (source) background image to each of them with different offset like this:

```
.piece-1 {
   background-image: url("...");
   background-position: right <CALCULATED RIGHT>px top <CALCULATED TOP>px;
}
```